# Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.3:8181/ready: dial tcp 10.244.0.3:8181: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, coredns

I am new to Kubernetes trying to build kubernetes cluster by kubeadm and I have crossed the stage till kube init (with args PFB command FYR) but the CoreDNS pod is failing with **CrashLoopBackOff** state. I have tried to check the event of that pod and got the below error. I am not sure to which service its calling and why it gets a connection refused. Could you please help me to fix this issue? PFB commands which I have executed.

kubeadm init:

```sh
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 \
   --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.2
```

CNI network plugin:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Namespace command:

```sh
root@kube-master:/etc# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-5z9f6              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   32         143m
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-tsjdj              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   32         143m
kube-system   etcd-kube-master                      1/1     Running            0          143m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kube-master            1/1     Running            0          143m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kube-master   1/1     Running            0          143m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-2kklk           1/1     Running            0          123m
kube-system   kube-proxy-5p9jf                      1/1     Running            0          143m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kube-master            1/1     Running            0          143m
```

coredns-event check:

```yaml
root@kube-master:/etc# kubectl describe pod coredns-66bff467f8-tsjdj -n kube-system
Name:                 coredns-66bff467f8-tsjdj
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 kube-master/192.168.0.142
Start Time:           Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:54:45 -0400
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=66bff467f8
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.244.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/coredns-66bff467f8
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://20d8697b21f1bfe955de6769abfbb18c658f3c4134a2505f580b8146c998871d
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:2c8d61c46f484d881db43b34d13ca47a269336e576c81cf007ca740fa9ec0800
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 10 Jul 2020 17:55:00 -0400
      Finished:     Fri, 10 Jul 2020 17:55:01 -0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  32
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-2w9w6 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-2w9w6:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-2w9w6
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                  Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                  -------
  Warning  BackOff    13m (x523 over 123m)    kubelet, kube-master  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  9m18s                   kubelet, kube-master  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.3:8181/ready: dial tcp 10.244.0.3:8181: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Pulled     7m42s (x4 over 9m23s)   kubelet, kube-master  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    7m42s (x4 over 9m22s)   kubelet, kube-master  Created container coredns
  Normal   Started    7m41s (x4 over 9m21s)   kubelet, kube-master  Started container coredns
  Warning  BackOff    4m14s (x26 over 9m17s)  kubelet, kube-master  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue in the old and latest version as well. coredns forward query was in the loop state and it got exited once it detects the loop. Please check this URL for more details - https://coredns.io/plugins/loop/#troubleshooting

I did check my /etc/resolv.conf and my nameserver was 127.0.1.1 so it detects the loops to forward the DNS query. So I have changed my network config as per below

https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away

Now its working fine. Even I didnt edit the coredns yaml file to add 8181 port to ready.

```
root@kube-master:/etc# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-522nr              1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-8qskt              1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-system   etcd-kube-master                      1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kube-master            1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kube-master   1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4jbpb           1/1     Running   0          10m
kube-system   kube-proxy-hz94b                      1/1     Running   0          11m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kube-master            1/1     Running   0          11m
```

coredns log

```
root@kube-master:/etc# kubectl logs coredns-66bff467f8-522nr -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.7
linux/amd64, go1.13.6, da7f65b
```

coredns pod event:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                    From                  Message
  ----     ------            ----                   ----                  -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  118s (x12 over 3m27s)  default-scheduler     0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Normal   Scheduled         107s                   default-scheduler     Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-66bff467f8-522nr to kube-master
  Normal   Pulled            98s                    kubelet, kube-master  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           96s                    kubelet, kube-master  Created container coredns
  Normal   Started           94s                    kubelet, kube-master  Started container coredns
```

Thanks for all your help @Abdennour TOUMI and @HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your coredns configmap and add the readiness flag:

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit coredns -o yaml
```

You will get the YAML definition for Edit.. add the line `ready :8181` as below (if not exist):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.as-gmbh.de in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods verified
           upstream
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        ready :8181 # <----  Ignore other lines and Focus Here 
        forward .  172.18.2.21
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your respone @Abdennour Toumi, I have tried the command which you gave but i get below error 

`root@kube-master:/etc# kubectl -n kube-system edit coredns -o yaml
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "coredns"
`

Comment: I have tried with below command where I am able to edit the file as you said. But still my coredns is not up and running :(

edit command:
`kubectl -n kube-system edit cm coredns -o yaml`

Comment: coredns events

`Normal   SandboxChanged          6m17s (x4 over 6m35s)  kubelet, kube-master  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Created                 5m23s (x3 over 6m12s)  kubelet, kube-master  Created container coredns
  Normal   Started                 5m23s (x3 over 6m11s)  kubelet, kube-master  Started container coredns
  Warning  BackOff                 91s (x25 over 6m9s)    kubelet, kube-master  Back-off restarting failed container`

Comment: I have tried from kubeadm init again and changed the yaml file to include ready:8181 but i get same error again - Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.2:8181/ready: dial tcp 10.244.0.2:8181: connect: connection refused

Comment: could you try `kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment/coredns `

Comment: I have tried it... but still i get same error connection refusd

Comment: could you please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Does the output of: `kubectl logs -n kube-system coredns-xxxxx-xxxxx` show anything? @Kavin

Comment: This is the log of coredns

`.:53
2020-07-13T17:21:10.623Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.3.1
2020-07-13T17:21:10.623Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.4, 6b56a9c
CoreDNS-1.3.1
linux/amd64, go1.11.4, 6b56a9c
2020-07-13T17:21:10.623Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 599b9eb76b8c147408aed6a0bbe0f669
2020-07-13T17:21:10.627Z [FATAL] plugin/loop: Loop (127.0.0.1:46379 -> :53) detected for zone ".", see https://coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Query: "HINFO 4060514592483885197.4525552591752936979."
`

Comment: as i was having issues, i am trying to use kubernetes - 1.14 version and i got the above log